# Python Report Builder

Tags: python, api, csv

I am building a report generator that requests certain information through an API and then parse(s)/writes the response to a CSV file.

I have all this working fine.

The trouble lies when there is an 'empty' field in the API response. This causes the columns in the CSV to 'collapse'.

Example

```
URL  CATEGORY  USER
URL  USER
URL  CATEGORY  USER
```

Heres an example of the raw API response containing Two lines *(The line begins with **{"url"**)*. The second is missing 'sales_tax_value' so would some how need an empty field inserting to compensate:

```
{
    "expenses": [
        {
            "url": "xxxxxx",
            "user": " xxxxxx ",
            "project": " xxxxxx ",
            "category": "xxxxxx ",
            "dated_on": "xxxxxx ",
            "currency": "xxxxxx ",
            "gross_value": "xxxxxx",
            "native_gross_value": " xxxxxx ",
            "sales_tax_rate": " xxxxxx ",
            "sales_tax_value": " xxxxxx ",
            "native_sales_tax_value": " xxxxxx",
            "description": " xxxxxx ",
            "mileage": " xxxxxx ",
            "engine_size_index": "xxxxxx",
            "engine_type_index": "xxxxxx",
            "vehicle_type": "xxxxxx",
            "initial_rate_mileage": " xxxxxx ",
            "have_vat_receipt": "xxxxxx",
            "updated_at": " xxxxxx ",
            "created_at": " xxxxxx "
        },
        {
            "url": "xxxxxx",
            "user": " xxxxxx ",
            "project": " xxxxxx ",
            "category": "xxxxxx ",
            "dated_on": " xxxxxx ",
            "currency": " xxxxxx ",
            "gross_value": " xxxxxx ",
            "native_gross_value": " xxxxxx ",
            "sales_tax_rate": " xxxxxx ",
            "description": " xxxxxx ",
            "mileage": " xxxxxx ",
            "engine_size_index": "xxxxxx",
            "engine_type_index": "xxxxxx",
            "vehicle_type": " xxxxxx ",
            "initial_rate_mileage": " xxxxxx ",
            "have_vat_receipt": "xxxxxx",
            "updated_at": " xxxxxx ",
            "created_at": " xxxxxx "
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried a long number of 'if' statements to check if each 'header' is present and if not append it to the line but this has so far been unsuccessful. This has resulted in creating some large (1.1GB) CSV files. I have put this down to poorly written loops on my part.

Any pointers would be much appreciated and if any further details are needed please let me know.

Comment: show us your code, so we can tell how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`csv.DictWriter()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), you can pass your dictionaries **directly** to the writer, and it'll handle missing keys for you:

```
 import csv

 with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfh:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(outfh, fieldnames=('url', 'category', 'user'), extrasaction='ignore')
     writer.writerows(data['expenses'])
```

Note:

1. The `fieldnames` argument specifies which keys `csv.DictWriter()` will use to write to the CSV file.
2. The `extrasaction='ignore'` keyword argument tells the writer to just ignore any other keys in the dictionary.
3. Any missing keys in the input dictionary use the `restval` argument, which defaults to the empty string. This means that if the 'category' key is missing, the column will still be added to the output file as an empty value.
4. You can just pass in the *whole* `expenses` list in one go to `writer.writerows()`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the great tip. I used the CSV module but read the response using json.loads prior to passing it through the csv writer.

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Declare of list of the fields you want to be output to the CSV file:

```
fields = ['url', 'category', 'user']
```

Then loop over the items in the response, and get the value or default it:

```
for expense in response['expenses']:
    data = [expense.get(field, '') for field in fields]
    # do whatever
```